# What is the correct way to test multiple android clients?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I have a working "client-server" program , client is an android app and the server uses a webservice. I'd like to simulate multiple android clients that will run my app to connect to this server.

How can I simulate this situation on Android Studio?

I tried to launch 2 emulators and it worked fine, but in my specific case I have to simulate a situation of 4 or 6 clients working parallel.
I couldn't launch more than 2 emulators- since I get this message "The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit. qtest is not supported under Windows"

So how do people simulate multiple clients?

*Just to make it clear- every 2 clients are supposed play a game together on the server, so my plan is to make sure that more than one couple can use the server- and this is why I need 4 or 6 working clients.

Answer (score 0):

I would have tested it on alpha testing stage as a correct way to test. Is this a possibility for you to do or you restricting yourself to emulators?

Comment: What is alpha testing? Like uploading it to the store?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a possibility to also implement the app on several devices, then I think you will have to just test reduced functionality. For instance, you could set up a since client to provide messages as if it were 6 separate clients just to test the webservice.

Comment: I don't have 4 devices for this thing, but I still want to test full functionality.